# In Dapper, Is It Optional to Create PK and FK relations within SQL Database?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I will be using Dapper as ORM within my .NET Core web application. My only concern is we have to do relational mapping within application as well. If I already have implemented Primary Key and Foreign keys for my tables within SQL database, then will it conflict when I create relational mapping within my web application. For example, If I have a class **Person** has **Education** class with one-to-many mapping. In .NET class within Person class, I written relation 
as:

```
List<Education> edu = new List<Education>;
```

Is it OK or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper plays no hand in the formation of the relationships within your app itself, in context of your classes and the relationships between them.

You can think of it as a set of database utilities to make using ADO.NET simpler. It will work seamlessly with whatever classes you design, and map your database records to you pocos for you.

It **will not** however hydrate your relationships for you. That will be on you to perform.

Comment: Thanks! By the way what does it mean by? "It will not however hydrate your relationships for you. That will be on you to perform."

Comment: Good question. All I mean by that, is that if your poco has a nested poco or poco collection, dapper won't retrieve that data for you a la entity framework via navigation properties.